# Should "css" and "stylesheet" tags be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

- [css](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/css) - 384
- [stylesheet](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stylesheet) - 14

Answer (score 2):

"stylesheet" should be a synonym for "css"

Comment: I agree. They should be merged.

Comment: I also agree for merging these two tags (from _stylesheet_ to _css_).

Comment: Yep makes sense good work as usual.